# How to add an item with all its subitems in Telerik gridListView

Tags: vb.net, telerik

I have a serious PEBKAC problem with some Telerik UI for Winforms controls. One of them is radListView. It seems that i am unable to understand the documentation of that element. All i want to do is add an item to the radListView control and its subitems, to fill the whole row which is a four-columns row.

For example: FirstName, LastName, E-Mail, Phone

I need a way to populate these by using vb.net.

Comment: why not use a GridView instead?

Comment: @NullException not using GridView because i need to populate static items at this time. I won't populate items from any local or remote DB or something. Just expirimenting.